# Query parameters before fragment in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fragment, query-string

Using for example

```
var myCode = ($location.search()).code
```

and pointing browser to `http://localhost/#/?code=123` will set `myCode = 123` but with browser pointing to `http://localhost/?code=123#/` will leave myCode empty.

I think this is different behaviour than described in the angular docs. Angular docs describe this:
[image: angularlocation]

Am I missing something here or is there no good way of reading the query parameters that are before the fragment?

Comment: You might need to explictly set the url mode. See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: Yes, with html5 mode enabled it seems to work as expected.

Comment: I will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to expliclty set HTML5 mode. You can do it when configuring the $locationProvider

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location for more details